# My usb ports are burning my flash drives. Why?

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-flash-drive, power-supply, usb-3

So I just assembled a new computer and I have a ASUS Rampage IV Extreme with a Intel i7-3820 CPU. I have Corsair 650W power supply and I connected it to the motherboard using the 24-pin connecter and the 12V 4pin connector, I thought that this might be the problem but it seems that is correct from this question: [Is the 4-pin PSU connector required? (Trying to connect a PSU to a mini case.)](https://superuser.com/questions/432234/is-the-4-pin-psu-connector-required-trying-to-connect-a-psu-to-a-mini-case)

So it seems that everytime I connect a USB drive to install my operating system from the USB drive the flash drive works for a few minutes and then burns and doesn't work on any other computer anymore. I am not sure yet if it is all the USB ports or just the ones built on the tower case, or perhaps just the blue USB-3 Port but now I can't afford to experiment and burn more flash drives.

I don't even know if this has anything to do with the power supply but it was the only thing I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably NOT the PSU or how it's attached.

If it's just the front panel USB ports on the chassis, ensure you hooked them to the right header on the motherboard, the right way around.  But if they work as expected at all (before dying), then it's hooked up right.

You should test the rear USB ports that are built directly onto the motherboard, if they blow out the flash drives as well, then you most likely have a faulty motherboard.

Comment: Maybe check for a screw on or near the USB ports.

Comment: Most likely, the USB headers were connected incorrectly from the case to the motherboard.

Comment: Yes I accidently connected the USB headers backwards to the motherboard transfering 5V+ instead of data!

Comment: I'm having this problem now with an older PC only with the front USB ports. They've always worked fine... it's something that just gradually happened over time. I'm running out of flash drives! It's a mystery to me.